# Undeletable/Unhideable/Unchangeable fields in Calendar List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, delete

I am making a Calendar in SharePoint, but I have some problems with the Title and Description fields.

I don't want the Description field at all, but I am unable to delete it in SharePoint Designer. I assume because this is a "sealed column".

I want to change the Title field to a lookup, but SharePoint Designer won't allow me to change the type of the Title field. My next idea was delete it and just make a new field, but it won't let me do that either.

Finally I decided I would just hide both of the fields and then makes the fields and make the fields I really wanted...but I can't hide them either.

Anyone have any ideas? Unfortunately, I can't use any programming because non-programmers will need to replicate my steps. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hide it from the content type. Follow steps below

1. Create a new Calendar
2. Open Calendar Settings
3. Under Content Types - Click on Event
4. Now Click on Title
5. Select Hidden and Click Ok
6. Do the same for description.

This will hide the fields from the View/Edit/New form.

I would strongly suggest you create a new Content Type based on Event. And hide as I suggested above. Then attach that content type to the calendar.